# Ionic GIFS Issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Having an issue loading GIFS in Ionic 3.

They load on Ionic serve, however they are not rendering on any mobile device. The pictures from the same API call will load, not the GIF's though.

Can't find any documentation on how to fix this.

Here is my code that is calling the images/gifs

```
<img id="image" align="center" class="mainPicture" src="{{content[indexCount].media}}" onError="this.src='assets/img/defeaultLogoPic.png'" />
```

Comment: can you test and render a gif from local folder (assets)?

Comment: also I would try for Angular2+ to use property binding: <img [src]="imagePath">

Comment: Going back and forth between here and Ionic - but I used your syntax above and it's still not rendering the GIFS on mobile. It does render them on ionic serve. @SergeyRudenko